# #each with partials and dynamic pages with handlebars/express

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm trying to do a foreach with partials into expressjs project, but I don't get

main.hbs

```
{{#each pages}}
   {{>this}}
{{/each}}
```

app.js

```
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
   
  let pages = ['test1','teste2']
  res.render('index',{user:req.user,pages:pages})

})
```

Then show me this message

Error: The partial this could not be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Handlebars documentation](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html#dynamic-partials) states that `dynamic` partials require parentheses around the expression that evaluates to the partial name. So one would think that `{{> (this) }}` would be sufficient.

However, in my experiments with this, I could not get this to work. Without digging deeply into the source, I assume there is something special about how `this` is parsed in this context. Therefore, to get it to work, I had to use `as` to give me an aliased reference to each page name. My template became:

```
{{#each pages as |page|}}
   {{> (page) ..}}
{{/each}}
```

Note: The `..` is there to set the parent object of `pages` as the context of the partial.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/emkzgn7p/) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you my friend !!! Now it works !!!